# Passing variables to jsx

Tags: adobe, jsx, adobe-indesign, adobe-scriptui

I have a rather nice jsx file that creates mixed inks swatches. It pops a ui that lets users select what sheet size, swatch shape, swatch size, starting color, ending color, increment steps, etc.

I am new to html etc. and need to figure out how to pass all the ui selections to the jsx script that I have.

Thank you kindly,

Comment: The question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow, but you need to look at using ExtendScript and write your own code to connect two different files.  You can include one file into another or just merge the code into a single file

Comment: Thank you Nicolai for your comment. In any CEP plugin, you'll have a UI whose user-defined values will passed to a JSX file. How is that done exactly?

Comment: You need to use csInterface.evalScript(). A good guide is here: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides